Python Windows service identifies correct registry key path, but doesn't retrieve the stored values
I'm making a Windows service, one of it's functions is to retrieve the stored values from the registry.
The standalone python script works as intended, but when I try running it as a Windows service, it doesn't retrieve the stored values from the registry
    # Default control targets
    self.control_list = ["none", "none", "none", "none"]
    # Stored control targets
    self.settings = QSettings("CompanyName", "ProductName")
    self.load_volume_targets()

    logging.info(self.settings.fileName())

def load_volume_targets(self):
    saved_targets = self.settings.value("currentlySavedVolumeTargets", [])
    if isinstance(saved_targets, list) and len(saved_targets) == 1:
        targets = saved_targets[0].split(", ")
        self.control_list = targets
        logging.info("Saved control targets loaded:", self.control_list)

The service correctly logs the correct path with logging.info(self.settings.fileName())
\HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\CompanyName\ProductName
The standalone script finds and prints out the saved values correctly:
Saved control targets loaded: ['Master', 'None', 'None', 'None']
\HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\CompanyName\ProductName

The code is the same for the standalone script and the service, both of them are in a class.
How can I debug why can't the service retrieve the values from the regstry?

Is there a HKEY_CURRENT_USER for a service? Perhaps you want to use HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE instead.

I'm using QSettings from PyQT6, it stores the values in HKEY_CURRENT_USER

maybe this might help Services and the Registry

Ok, you were correct the first time, after failing to impersonate the user, I just changed where the values were stored instead of HKEY_CURRENT_USER to HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE and it works fine now, thank you.
